# how can I repair or restore the format or volumes in my windows 7 HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

Something has gone wrong with a windows 7 HDD I am using externally ( in a USB caddy ). Previously I was able to access files on it as normal using my windows 10 laptop.

But then, when I tried reading from it using the file explorer my windows 10 laptop came up with...you need to format this drive ! (which I did NOT do !).

I assumed that somehow the formatting or partitioning of the HDD has gone wrong ?
I have tried various methods, but I cannot resolve the problem.

I tried using the standard windows command chkdsk. That scans the HDD Ok, list the number of files, etc and says … no problem found...

I even purchased the partition repair tool from https://www.file-recovery.com/recovery.html That tool was able to display various folders and files. It could not repair any partition, it responds with ...that partition is a logical partition...
I then tried using the various options and features, including ' fix boot sector '

Now the problem is;- when I try to access the drive with the standard Windows File Explorer it shows... system reserve F … empty
Local disk G … is not accessible

How can I repair / restore the HDD so that I can use it as normal ( read, copy files, etc )

Answer (score 0):

1. Pull your data off of the hard drive first so that you have a backup. The drive itself may be failing.
2. Check the SMART status of the drive to see if it has any obvious errors.  If it does, you should replace the drive.  You can use tools like SeaTools, CrystalDisk Info, or HD Tune for this.
3. If it looks healthy, reformat it with Disk Management in Windows. (Do not choose the Quick Format option).  Then copy your data back to it.
4. If it happens again after the reformat, replace the drive.

Personally, I would opt to replace the drive because I like to be extra confident that my HDDs are stable.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I repair / restore the HDD so that I can use it as normal ( read, copy files, etc )

Try out the free and open source software Testdisk at [www.cgsecurity.org](http://www.cgsecurity.org)